# Declare type for imported module that allows undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, casting

I'm using a module that has a TS def like:

```js
// index.d.ts

interface SomeContext {
  // ... other props

  thing?: Record<string, any>;
}
```

When we use this module, we guard on `someContext.thing` being defined so it's never undefined when we start using it. We want to give it our own type in our code since we'll know what the shape will be but have had to do the following to get it to pass the TS build:

```js
const { thing: ourThing } = <{ thing: any }>someContext.thing;
```

This feels like the wrong way to go about it as we lose the safety and DX that TS usually gives us.

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

When you are positive that thing is defined you can use the exclamation mark operator (non-null assertion operator) to tell the compiler that you know the value will not be null/undefined.

`const thing = someContext.thing!;`